# Vertical center to an img (svg) within an a tag

Tags: html, css, svg

So I wanted to center vertically the config button (#config) I tried too many options but not even one that I would like and understand. So here is my CodePen:

> http://codepen.io/fenwil/pen/ONRXwz

This is the most important part of the code to modify:

HTML

```
<header id="cabecera">
    <img id="logo" alt="Mayor Igual a Siete" src="http://imgh.us/logo_207.svg">
    <h3 id="user">Username</h3>
    <a href="perfil.html"><img alt="Configuracion" src="http://imgh.us/config.svg" id="config"></a>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#config {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance! And if you see something else badly donde let me know please!

Answer (score 1):

and if you add a new line with this?

```
#config{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and it works! But isn't there a way to center vertically everything? or why the #config isn't centering? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the floats and use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cabecera {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top:50px; /* for demo only */
}
#cabecera,
a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#cabecera {
  background-color: #393E46;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#cabecera * {
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}
#user,
#config {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 55px;
  float: left;
}
#config {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
#config:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#user {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header id="cabecera">
  <img id="logo" alt="Mayor Igual a Siete" src="http://imgh.us/logo_207.svg">
  <h3 id="user">Username</h3>
  <a href="perfil.html">
    <img alt="Configuracion" src="http://imgh.us/config.svg" id="config">
  </a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center just about anything:

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
}

.content
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

remove unneeded directions

---

**How it works:** top/left percentage positioning work on the size of the parent, causing the upper left corner of the inner element to be moved to the center of the parent element. To really center the element you then have to `transform: translate` the element by -50%, which skales on the size of the element itself resulting in a perfect center

Comment: Great! This is one of the more accurate solutions that I try but when I want to use a hover with transform scale or rotate in #config for example it' doesnt work really good. Any thoughts on how to make it work?

Comment: Sure, you can combine transform properties by simply setting your hover to `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg)`. The only problem there is, is the fact that you (currently) can't combine `transform` property values over multiple lines/classes/files so you will have to define it as stated in your hover selector (which reduces reusability)